# New Installation using CM 5.5.1 urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying a brand new installation on a 3 node cluster running CentOS 6.6  using Cloudera Manager 5.5.1,however on step # 7 named "Installing Selected Parcels" , I get an error that says

```
<urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument> - server1.mydomain.com
<urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument> - server2.mydomain.com
<urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument> - server3.mydomain.com
```

I am not sure what the issue is , can someone let me know if this is a known issue ?

**Upon further investigation , I see the following error in the log scm-agent.log**

```
[25/Dec/2015 08:16:10 +0000] 18222 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Finished download [ url: http://0.1.55.217:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11-el6.parcel, state: exception, total_bytes: 0, downloaded_bytes: 0, start_time: 2015-12-25 08:16:10, download_end_time: , end_time: 2015-12-25 08:16:10, code: 600, exception_msg: <urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument>, path: None ]
[25/Dec/2015 08:16:25 +0000] 18222 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Starting download of: http://0.1.55.217:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11-el6.parcel
[25/Dec/2015 08:16:25 +0000] 18222 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     /opt/cloudera/parcel-cache/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11-el6.parcel.part exists, add Range header: bytes=0-
[25/Dec/2015 08:16:25 +0000] 18222 Thread-13 downloader   ERROR    Unexpected exception during download
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/downloader.py", line 276, in _download
    response = self.opener.fetch_url(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/downloader.py", line 69, in fetch_url
    return urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1190, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument>
[25/Dec/2015 08:16:25 +0000] 18222 Thread-13 downloader   INFO     Finished download [ url: http://0.1.55.217:7180/cmf/parcel/download/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11-el6.parcel, state: exception, total_bytes: 0, downloaded_bytes: 0, start_time: 2015-12-25 08:16:25, download_end_time: , end_time: 2015-12-25 08:16:25, code: 600, exception_msg: <urlopen error [Errno 22] Invalid argument>, path: None ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check to see that your agent node can telnet to the manager node on port 7180.

I was seeing issues where my agent nodes couldn't resolve the manager dns.  So I had to map the DNS on my agent nodes in /etc/hosts.